# Creating a comma seperated csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, csv, text

I have array reference like this

```
a1 = [["http://ww.amazon.com"],["failed"]]
```

When i write it to csv file it is written like

```
["http://ww.amazon.com"]
["failed"]
```

But i want to write like

```
http://ww.amazon.com   failed
```

Comment: When you ask a question for help with code, it is really important to show us what code you've written. It's a lot better, and easier, for us to correct your code than it is for us to write something and you try to jam it into place.

Answer (score 3):

#### First you need to flatten the array `a1`

```
b1 = a1.flatten # => ["http://ww.amazon.com", "failed"]
```

#### Then you need to generate the CSV by passing every row (array) to the following `csv` variable:

```
require 'csv'
csv_string = CSV.generate({:col_sep => "\t"}) do |csv|
  csv << b1
end
```

`:col_sep =>"\t"` is used to insert a `tab` separator in each row.

Change the value of `:col_sep => ","` for using comma.

#### Finally you have the `csv_string` containing the correct form of the csv

Comment: Yeah it works but how could i add a new line for priniting next array results?

Comment: For adding a new row to the csv, all you need is `csv << new_row`.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's built-in CSV class is your starting point. From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) for writing to a CSV file:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

For your code, simply flatten your array:

```
[['a'], ['b']].flatten # => ["a", "b"]
```

Then you can assign it to the parameter of the block (`csv`) which will cause the array to be written to the file:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('file.csv', 'wb') do |csv|
  csv << [["row"], ["of"], ["CSV"], ["data"]].flatten
end
```

Saving and running that creates "file.csv", which contains:

```
row,of,CSV,data
```

Your question is written in such a way that it sounds like you're trying to generate the CSV file by hand, rather than rely on a class designed for that particular task. On the surface, creating a CSV seems easy, however it has nasty corner cases and issues to be handled when a string contains spaces *and* the quoting character used to delimit strings. A well-tested, pre-written class can save you a lot of time writing and debugging code, or save you from having to explain to a customer or manager why your data won't load correctly into a database.

But that leaves the question, why does your array contain sub-arrays? Usually that happens because you're doing something wrong as you gather the elements, and makes me think your question should really be about how do you avoid doing that. (It's called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)